# nativescript classic bluetooth native android api

Tags: android, bluetooth, nativescript

this is my first question, i'm trying to realize an app with nativescript that will communicate with classic bluetooth devices. at the beginning i've tried the well known EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth nativescript plugin, but this works only with BLE devices, i can turn on the bluetooth interface but i can't see no bluetooth devices around me.

i've read many pages about android and native api:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp

http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-programmatically-scan-or-discover-android-bluetooth-device/

and many others, so is there a way to integrate native android bluetooth api in nativescript? someone of you could help me?

this is my function, at the onDiscovered i ahave no results:

```
exports.bt = function () {    
    bluetooth.isBluetoothEnabled().then(
        function (enabled) {
            console.log("Enabled? " + enabled);
            if (!enabled) {
                bluetooth.enable().then(
                    function(enabled) {
                        console.log("active: "+ enabled);
                        bluetooth.startScanning({
                            serviceUUIDs: [],
                            seconds: 10,
                            onDiscovered: function (peripheral) {
                                console.log("Periperhal found with UUID: " + peripheral.UUID);
                            }
                        }).then(function () {
                            console.log("scanning complete ");
                            console.log("Periperhal found with UUID: " + peripheral.UUID);
                        }, function (err) {
                            console.log("error while scanning: " + err);
                        });
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    );
};
```

thanks in advance

**EDIT

this library works only with BLE devices

Comment: When you say 'I have no results' what do you mean exactly? And please provide the sufficient context when asking for help on SO. From the code above, it does not become clear what the `bluetooth` variable is.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, the bluetooth varible is :

    var bluetooth = require("nativescript-bluetooth");

as indicated in the official page of the plugin:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-bluetooth

when i say that i have "no result" i mean in the console log it prints `console.log("active: "+ enabled);` 
(with enabled true) and then  `console.log("scanning complete ");`

anyway, the real problem is that this plugin is for BLE devices and not for classic bluetooth devices. 

thank you

Comment: Make sure to include that information in the original post.

Comment: Hi. I am facing the same issue. Did u find any solutions?

Comment: wich issue? the classic bluetooth doesn't work, it's for BLE devices